# Using Selenium in Python to click through all elements with the same class name

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, click

I am trying to click on all of the "like" buttons on a webpage.  I know how to click on one of them, but I'd like to be able to click them all.  They have the same class name, but different id's.

Do I need to create some sort of list and tell it to click on each one of the items on the list? Is there a way to write "click all"?

Here's what my code looks like (I removed the login code):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.set_window_size(650, 700)
browser.get('http://iconosquare.com/viewer.php#/tag/searchterm/grid')

mobile = browser.find_element_by_id('open-menu-mobile')
mobile.click()
search = browser.find_element_by_id('getSearch')
search.click()
search.send_keys('input search term' + Keys.RETURN)

#this gets me to the page I want to click the likes
fitness = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("a[href*='fitness/']")
fitness.click()

#here are the different codes I've tried to use to click all of the "like buttons"

#tried to create a list of all elements with "like" in the id and click on all of them.  It didn't work.
like = browser.find_elements_by_id('like')
for x in range(0,len(like)):
    if like[x].is_displayed():
        like[x].click()

#tried to create a list by class and click on everything within the list and it didn't work.
like = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('like_picto_unselected')
like.click()

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'
```

I know I can't click on a list because it isn't a single object, but I have no idea how I'd go about this otherwise.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: someone answered a similar question on java, but I don't know how to convert it to Python or if it is even possible.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15537930/getting-list-of-items-inside-div-using-selenium-webdriver

Comment: Did my solution not resolve the issue?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is unfortunate, you got two halves of the whole, you cannot find multiple elements by id as ID is unique to a single element.

so combine the iterative method you use with id and the find by elements with classes to get:

```
like = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('like_picto_unselected')
for x in range(0,len(like)):
    if like[x].is_displayed():
        like[x].click()
```

I strongly suspect this will work for you. Please tell me if not.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response!! It worked perfectly.  I had no idea that you could only find one element using the find_id method.

Comment: this works awesome! would it be possible to do a print on how many are found? or how many it clicked?

Comment: @droopie you can just use ```len(like)``` to get the number of elements found with that class name. Meanwhile, to get the number of buttons that were clicked, you can just create an extra variable and increment it below the if block to get that count!