# How to find this element in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

In the web page, there is many elements like this below and I want to find all of them and click one after one.
they have the same name of class but different by ID.

How I can find it and click?

```
<a class="do do-task btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-block" href="javascript:;" data-task-id="1687466" data-service-type="3" data-do-class="do-task" data-getcomment-href="/tasks/getcomment/" data-check-count="0" data-max-check-count="2" data-money-text="0.08"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">0.08 </font></font><i class="far fa-ruble-sign"></i></a>
```

Comment: use find_elements function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Selenium in Python to click through all elements with the same class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31349788/using-selenium-in-python-to-click-through-all-elements-with-the-same-class-name)

Answer (score 0):

To identify all of the similar elements and create a *list* you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  element_list = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.do.do-task.btn.btn-sm.btn-primary.btn-block[data-task-id]")))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  element_list = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='do do-task btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-block' and @data-task-id]")))
  ```

Next, you can access each list item and invoke `click()` on each of them one by one.

- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If this css

```
a.do.do-task.btn.btn-sm.btn-primary.btn-block
```

represent them, then you can use the below code :

```
for a in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a.do.do-task.btn.btn-sm.btn-primary.btn-block"):
    a.click()
```

You may have to scroll to each element or put some delay before click, this depends on your use case and your automation strategy.